# Extract information from a div and make some field parent of others

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract information from a relatively simple piece of code, but some blanks and `<br>` tag is wrong forming my json file.

This is the main div with contents:

[image: main_div]

Which has the code:

```
<div class="caixanorm">
   <div id="titulo">
      <a href="http://quonde.com.br/club-4/" rel="bookmark" title="Link para CLUB 4">
         <h2>CLUB 4</h2>
         <h3 id="subtitulo">Academia                             </h3>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div id="endereco">
      (61) 3346-7423<br>
      CRS 515, entrada W2                
   </div>
   <div id="servecat">
      Em <a href="http://quonde.com.br/asasul/esporte/academias/" rel="category tag">Academias</a> da  <a href="http://quonde.com.br/quadras/516-515/" rel="tag">516 / 515</a> Sul
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my code:

-`item.py`

```
import scrapy

class QuondeItem(scrapy.Item):
    localizacao = scrapy.Field()  #location
    titulo = scrapy.Field()       #title
    subtitulo = scrapy.Field()    #subtitle
    telefone = scrapy.Field()     #phone
    endereco = scrapy.Field()     #address
    categoria = scrapy.Field()    #category
    quadra = scrapy.Field()       #block
```

-`my_spider.py`

```
import scrapy
from quonde.items import QuondeItem


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quonde"
    allowed_domains = ["quonde.com.br"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://quonde.com.br/quadras/516-515/",

    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        div = response.xpath('//div[@class="caixanorm"]')
        items = []
        for sel in div:
            item = QuondeItem()
            item['localizacao'] = sel.xpath('//h1[@class="inline"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['titulo'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="titulo"]/a/h2/text()').extract()
            item['subtitulo'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="titulo"]/a/h3/text()').extract()
            item['telefone'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="endereco"]/text()[1]').extract()
            item['endereco'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="endereco"]/text()[2]').extract()
            item['categoria'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="servecat"]/a[1]/text()').extract()
            item['quadra'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="servecat"]/a[@rel="tag"]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
            return items
```

As we can see, the first field of the `items.py` are not described in the div because I would like him to be the parent item and the rest were his children... but, this is what I get: [JSON Result](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2ea0acfbe3c379d69afaaf1ae279bfba). Telephones and addresses comes with HTML characters and whitespaces and I could not make the location of each block to be the father of all others ([image: explanation]).

Apart from that, I wonder if the formation of json itself is correct, for example, the title 0 corresponds to 0 subtitle, except that it should not be in one cell only and repeat for the other?

Sorry for English, thank right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem here is that *your XPath expressions are not relative to the current selector* - you need the **dot** at the beginning of every expression.

Also, you don't need to extract the location in the loop, do it before.

Also, in order to prettify the extracted fields, use an [Item Loader](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and input and output processors:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose


class QuondeItem(scrapy.Item):
    localizacao = scrapy.Field()  #location
    titulo = scrapy.Field()       #title
    subtitulo = scrapy.Field()    #subtitle
    telefone = scrapy.Field()     #phone
    endereco = scrapy.Field()     #address
    categoria = scrapy.Field()    #category
    quadra = scrapy.Field()       #block


class QuondeItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

The modified spider code:

```
import scrapy
from quonde.items import QuondeItem, QuondeItemLoader


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quonde"
    allowed_domains = ["quonde.com.br"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://quonde.com.br/quadras/516-515/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        div = response.xpath('//div[@class="caixanorm"]')
        location = response.xpath('.//h1[@class="inline"]/span/text()').extract()[0]
        for sel in div:
            loader = QuondeItemLoader(QuondeItem(), selector=sel)

            loader.add_value("localizacao", location)
            loader.add_xpath("titulo", './/div[@id="titulo"]/a/h2/text()')
            loader.add_xpath("subtitulo", './/div[@id="titulo"]/a/h3/text()')
            loader.add_xpath("telefone", './/div[@id="endereco"]/text()[1]')
            loader.add_xpath("endereco", './/div[@id="endereco"]/text()[2]')
            loader.add_xpath("categoria", './/div[@id="servecat"]/a[1]/text()')
            loader.add_xpath("quadra", './/div[@id="servecat"]/a[@rel="tag"]/text()')

            yield loader.load_item()
```

And here is the produced JSON output:

```
[{"subtitulo": "Laborat\u00f3rio", "categoria": "Cl\u00ednicas e Consult\u00f3rios", "quadra": "516 / 515", "telefone": "(61) 3245-1275", "endereco": "CRS 515, Bl. B, Loja 77", "titulo": "Micra", "localizacao": "516 / 515"},
{"subtitulo": "Pneus e Rodas", "categoria": "Autom\u00f3veis", "quadra": "516 / 515", "telefone": "(61) 3346-1666", "endereco": "CRS 515, Bl. B, Loja 14", "titulo": "Impacto", "localizacao": "516 / 515"},
...
{"subtitulo": "Cons\u00f3rcios", "categoria": "Consultorias e Assessorias", "quadra": "516 / 515", "telefone": "(61) 3346-8073", "endereco": "SHCS 516, Bl. C, Lj. 75", "titulo": "FERRAZ", "localizacao": "516 / 515"},
{"subtitulo": "Tape\u00e7aria", "categoria": "Decora\u00e7\u00f5es e Molduras", "quadra": "516 / 515", "telefone": "(61) 3245-3888", "endereco": "SHCS 516, Bl. C, Lj. 56", "titulo": "MUNDO DOS TAPETES", "localizacao": "516 / 515"}]
```

Comment: Why use the dot at beginning of expression?

Comment: @FilipeManuel otherwise, you are extracting every, for instance, subtitle on every iteration of the loop. You need to make it context-specific.

Comment: @FilipeManuel see also: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! This was exactly the way I needed to mount the json. About Location be the father of all the other fields, how can I do it later? I gave example with just a URL, but I have a 60.

Comment: @FilipeManuel glad to help, one option would probably be to have the item with the only  `location` field defined. Then, in the spider collect other field information into a list of dictionaries with you would set as a value of the location field and return/yield at the end of the parse method..hope that makes sense.